# Incredible's Newspaper Easter Egg?

Tags: pixar, the-incredibles, easter-egg

In Pixar's *The Incredibles*", in the scene where Bob finds out that Gazerbeam is dead from the newspapers, we can see the tombstone headline on the front cover, reading "Scientists Find the Missing Link." It seemed like a pretty intriguing article and you can see in earlier scenes that a lot of detail and thought was put into the papers by the designers, so I was wondering if this title might have been an Easter egg or reference to perhaps another movie?

I am aware that even taking Pixar Theory into account, *The Incredibles* is supposedly set in a different timeline, but I thought that perhaps it referred to the missing DNA link that caused super powers? I know it's a long shot but if anyone had any other info on this heading I would love to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the back cover, it's the tombstone headline on the front page. It also has the subheader "*The Astounding Story*". Beyond that, the writing below is unreadable and the picture (of buildings) doesn't seem relevant.

[image]

Unlike other easter eggs, this headline doesn't seem to relate to any of Pixar's prior or upcoming films. Best guess is that it was either a throwaway (we know that superpowers are almost certainly [genetic](http://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/the_incredibles.bmp)) or it might just be a super subtle reference to "[The Good Dinosaur](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1979388/)", a film that Incredibles voice actor Bob Peterson pitched to Pixar in the early 2000s.

Comment: Sorry about headline mistake, meant to edit that earlier.

Comment: My first thought was that it could be referring to the character 'The Missing Link', from Monsters Vs Aliens. 
Obviously different productions, but you never know...